# Hardness of finding eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a setting in which finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors is computationally hard? Or at least, not known to be computationally easy?

For example, how computationally hard or easy is it to find eigenvalues/eigenvectors of matrices over finite fields?  Suppose the field has size exponential in the dimension.  (Does the QR algorithm still converge?)

How about finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors of sparse matrices?

Comment: to determine hardness, you'll need to specify the input more precisely. How is the finite field presented to the algorithm ? Also, sparse matrices can only potentially make it easier to find eigenvalues, so the $O(n^3)$ procedure still applies, and therefore the problem is not hard.

Comment: Good point - Let's just say that the finite field is F_p for prime p.  Then just represent the field elements as you would integers.

Comment: Well, it seems finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors of matrices over finite fields is easy, thanks to Berlekamp's algorithm, etc.

Comment: so that part of the question is resolved ?

Comment: [corss-posted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49770/hardness-of-finding-eigenvalues-over-finite-fields)

Comment: Is the complexity of finding eigenvalues any easier if we consider symmetric matrices over the non negative integers?